# React Router only working for "/" route and not any other

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[I add all the routes here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id3bS.png)

[With all the same content.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngClK.png)

And in my browser for the "/ route" it works fine, it show's the text Home Page but when I go to /register or /login it shows: No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/register and No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/login

(**i'm using v6**)

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see. Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Images of code are not useful as they are not searchable or copy/pasteable, and can be more difficult to read, and are not accessible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Stumbled on the same problem. Someone comment a fix!

Answer (score 0):

=> Add "exact" keyword in each routes and instead of element, use "component". i.e

```
<Route path="/register" component={Register} exact />
```

Comment: OP is using `react-router-dom@6`, so the `Route` components have no `exact` or `component` props. See [Routes and Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route) for type declaration.

Comment: => In v6 of react-router-dom, we don't need to add "/" in front of routs, just remove "/" from your path. i.e  

```<Route path="register" component={Register} exact />```

Comment: This is not working